# Does iPad have accelerometer or gyro?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiaccelerometer

I have an iPhone app using these (via UIAccelerometer) - will it work on the iPad?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original iPad has an accelerometer. The iPad 2 has an accelerometer and a gyroscope.